# Grails- Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails

After migrating 1.2.2 to 2.3.5 we are getting grails domain objects caching issue.

We have three domain objects A ,B and C.

```
class A implements Serializable {
     static hasMany = [b: B] 
    static mappedBy = [b: 'aId'] //domain properits 
} 
class B implements Serializable { 
    static belongsTo = A 
    static hasMany = [c: C] 
    static mappedBy = [c: 'bId'] domain properties 
} 
class C implements Serializable {
    static hasMany = [d: D] 
    static mappedBy = [d: 'cId'] domain properties 
}
```

When We are trying to display list of details of these transactions ,multiple hibernate sql queries are exeucting. We are able to see first hibernate query it fetches all the data in one query.For Associations It seems populating child domain objects  it is executing again sql statements . It is taking so much time for processing the page.Did I miss anywhere configuration, please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: Have you checked that the database indexes on the tables for A, B, and C survived the migration?